# Is there a better way to implement the fibonacci formula using rational numbers?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading the [Learn you some Haskell for the Greater Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) book, as I was playing around with recursion in Haskell I implemented the fibonacci function, the recursive version is simple, probably can be improved:

```
-- recursive fibonacci numbers
rfib :: Int -> Int
rfib 0 = 0
rfib 1 = 1
rfib n =   rfib (n-1) + rfib(n-2)
```

As I was googling to learn more I stumbled upon this article: 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/what-fibonacci-taught-me-about

The author shows the fibonacci formula:

[image: Fibonacci Formula]

I decided to implement it in Haskell using rational numbers to avoid floating point imprecisions. My implementation looks like this:

```
fibMultiplier   = (toRational 1) / (toRational (sqrt 5))
firstFibTerm  n = (((toRational 1)  + (toRational (sqrt 5))) / toRational 2) ^ n
secondFibTerm n = (((toRational 1)  - (toRational (sqrt 5))) / toRational 2) ^ n

fib :: Int -> Int
fib n = truncate (fromRational (fibMultiplier * firstFibTerm n) - (fibMultiplier * secondFibTerm n))
```

As a beginner I am sure that the code above can be drastically improved, can you point me what can be improved or some mistakes I've made?

I apreciate the help.

**UPDATE**

So, after playing around with the suggestions, I found that using `Data.Real.Constructible` is fast and precise, with no rounding errors. My final implementation is:

```
fib :: Int -> Construct
fib n = ( ( (1 / (sqrt 5)) * ( (( 1 + (sqrt 5) ) / 2) ^ n ) ) -
          ( (1 / (sqrt 5)) * ( (( 1 - (sqrt 5) ) / 2) ^ n ) ) )::Construct
```

I also implemented a function that returns a list of the n fibonacci numbers:

```
fibList :: Int -> [Construct]
fibList n = [fib(x) | x <- [0..n]]
```

Using this function we can compare the results of the different implementations:

```
-- recursive fibonacci numbers
rfib :: Int -> Int
rfib 0 = 0
rfib 1 = 1
rfib n =   rfib (n-1) + rfib(n-2)

-- recursive fibonacci sequence
rfibList :: Int -> [Int]
rfibList n = [rfib(x) | x <- [0..n]]
-- rfibList 20 returns: [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765]


-----------------------------------


-- fibonacci number using Double and truncate
doubleFib :: Integer -> Integer
doubleFib n = truncate ( ( (1 / (sqrt 5)) * ( (( 1 + (sqrt 5) ) / 2) ^ n ) ) -
                         ( (1 / (sqrt 5)) * ( (( 1 - (sqrt 5) ) / 2) ^ n ) ) )

-- fibonacci list using Double and truncate
doubleFibList :: Integer -> [Integer]
doubleFibList n = [doubleFib(x) | x <- [0..n]]
-- doubleFibList 20 returns: [0,1,0,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,143,232,377,610,986,1597,2584,4181,6764]


-----------------------------------


-- fibonacci number using Construct
constructFib :: Int -> Construct
constructFib n = ( ( (1 / (sqrt 5)) * ( (( 1 + (sqrt 5) ) / 2) ^ n ) ) -
                   ( (1 / (sqrt 5)) * ( (( 1 - (sqrt 5) ) / 2) ^ n ) ) )::Construct

-- fibonacci list using construct
constructFibList :: Int -> [Construct]
constructFibList n = [constructFib(x) | x <- [0..n]]
-- constructFibList 20 returns: [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765]
```

Notice that we get a rounding error on the doubleFibList, the 16th number should be `987` but we get `986`. The recursive implementation is slow, the Double implementation is imprecise, but using Construct we can get a fast and precise fibonacci sequence, much better than my old implementation using toRational.

Comment: You should probably not use `Rational` since `sqrt 5` is irrational.  If you want to do this computation I'd just use `Double` then convert to `Integer` at the end.

Comment: @bheklilr You're better off using [exact values](http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/7150) in Z[√5]...

Comment: @gallais Precise values are great, but I'd be willing to wager that rounding a `Double` would be more efficient.  Besides, explaining what Z[√5] means would likely take more than the 500 characters allowed in a SO comment =P

Comment: Thank you guys, good to know that the double is good enough in this case. I did the test and for the first 30 numbers there is no difference between the recursive function and the Double version. I'll answer my question explaining my findings. In the mean time, could you guys point me where I can learn about Z[√5] ?

Comment: You can write a fast & exact implementation of Fibonacci using `Integer`s by using the method described in SICP, [in exercise 1.19](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_thm_1.19)

Comment: In my previous comment I said that I got no rounding errors the using `Double`, I was mistaken. I updated my question and accepted @josejuan's answer. `Constructible` is awesome. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You can't use your `sqrt` version, use `Data.Real.Constructible` instead)

```
import Data.Real.Constructible 

fib :: Int -> Construct 
fib n = (((1+sqrt(5))/2)^n - ((1-sqrt(5))/2)^n)/sqrt(5)
```

Comment: Something feels strange about using `Int` with `Construct`. Why not switch to `Integer`?

Comment: Thank you @josejuan, wow, Construct is like magic, it is faster than Integers. It solves the problem with no rounding errors, just like the recursive function. Thank you, I'm accepting your answer, it taught me a lot.

Comment: @EsdrasMayrink, you seem to have forgotten to actually accept it by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: Nah, I was updating my question, there you go :-) Thanks.